# Reduce gap between grid rows of text

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.top {
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
}
  
.bottom {
  grid-row: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="top">Top</span>
  <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
</span>
```

How can I move bottom and top vertically closer together?

I have tried

- `grid-gap: -10px` on `.container`
- `height: calc(100% - 10px)` on `.bottom`
- `top: -10px` on `.bottom`

But nothing changes in any case

Comment: The grid seems to be fine. Do you want the top and bottom elements to overlap?

Comment: what do you mean by reduce ? how much do you want to reduce ? :)

Comment: Can you add top and bottom margin and give a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height` to reduce the space between them. If that's what you are looking for. ( reduce space is a vague request )

Check below to compare ( first items have line-height added )

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.top {
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
}
  
.bottom {
  grid-row: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.top.custom {
  line-height:18px;
  }
  .bottom.custom {
  line-height:14px;
  }
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="top custom">Top</span>
  <span class="bottom custom">Bottom</span>
</span>

<span class="container">
  <span class="top">Top</span>
  <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
</span>
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me, because as well as getting it to look as I want it also resizes the bottom cell and grid overall to be shorter and reflect the visuals.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`translateY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY()) on `.bottom` (negative value) or `.top` (positive value)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.top {
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
}
  
.bottom {
  grid-row: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="top">Top</span>
  <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
</span>
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.top {
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}
  
.bottom {
  grid-row: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="top">Top</span>
  <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `margin: top` this will let you reduce the gap

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}



.top {
  font-size: 18px;
}
  
.bottom {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="top">Top</span>
  <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
</span>
```

Comment: You actually made a typo. It should be display: block; without the quotes. The margin-top also works without the display property set.